# mysql determine storage size of a field

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, storage, administration

i would like to know if there is a **mysql** command to determine the currently used actual storage size of a mysql field.

Maybe something like "show used_storage myfield FROM ... WHERE ..."

Oddly I couln'd find anything like this.

(The same for postgresql would be interessting too)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question would be more useful as two separate questions.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I also thought about that, but then I thought it would be nice to see how it works on both systems.
The main focus is on mysql though, postgres is just FYI for me)

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL you can use

```
SELECT your_column, pg_column_size(your_column)
FROM your_table
```

A complete list of this kind of functions is in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html

Comment: Wow, and again postgresql seems to be the better DB :) Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a character data field, the simplest would be

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(myField)) From MyTable
```

If you are using some numerical data type, you could just get a count on the rows, and multiply it by the size, for instance 4 for INTEGER, or 8 for DOUBLE.

It won't reflect the actual size taken up on disk however. This is probably a lot more difficult to find out. And even if it was accurate, the actual size of the table could be much more than the total size of all the columns due to fragmentation and other factors.

You can get the size (and index size) of an entire table with:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'MyTable';
```

If you copy out just the column you want to a new temporary table, you may be able to get a more realistic view of how much space your field is actually taking up on disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

But I am more searching for a command that shows me the "real" space required.
For a longtext field for example, there is 4 byte used, disregarding how much you store in it. And additionally if the value is big, the data is stored externally and about 700 bytes will additionally remain in the column.
Which means the whole size will be something more than the actual size of the content.
That is the value I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL documents space utilization:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: When a man asks question on SO I'm sure in 99% he knows about documentation. Probably he just don't have time to examine it, spend time on experiments. He just wants to get simple answer which will help him quickly.